# How to override __setitem__ for a function's globals dict?

Tags: python, overriding

I want to be able to intercept variable assignments within a function and execute custom code.  I have tried creating a custom dict as follows:

```
class userdict(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        print 'run my code'
        dict.__setitem__(self, key, value)
```

If I exec code using this as the global dict, then my custom code will run on each variable assignment.  e.g.:

```
UserDict = userdict()
exec 'x = 1' in UserDict
#outputs 'run my code'
```

But if my code is inside a function, it doesn't work:

```
code = """
def foo():
    global x
    x = 1
"""
exec code in UserDict
UserDict['foo']()
```

In this case, 'x' is assigned, but my custom code does not run.  I assume that within a function, the global dict is being modified somehow without calling setitem.  Is this correct? Is there a way to intercept variable assignments within a function and execute custom code?

I want to do this in order to synchronize certain objects available inside a function with other objects in my program.  In order words, when the an assignment to certain variables occurs inside the function, that change should propagate to other variables in my program.

Comment: Are you trying to override what happens when assigning to global variables, or do you also want to hook in when assigning to local variables?  Neither one is a good idea, but the former may be possible with some fragile, sneaky hack.  The latter is probably impossible.

Comment: You can't replace the global module dict with your own impementation and expect it to work. Really what should be happening is that these functions should be emitting some kind of signal or callback to allow other data structures to respond. It shouldn't be a black box situation where variables just randomly change on you.

Comment: I'm only concerned about overriding what happens when assigning to global variables.

Comment: Both your examples, `exec 'x = 1' in UserDict` and `exec code in UserDict` print `run my code` for me.

Comment: @martineau The `'run my code'` you get when doing `exec code in UserDict` is because `exec` is setting the function `foo`, but then if you do `UserDict['foo']()` the custom dictionary's `__setitem__` is not called.
[At least, this is what I understood].

Answer (score 3):

The issue might be that builtin `dict` methods don't call overridden in subclasses methods in CPython. Pypy, Jython call custom `__setitem__()` so they see immediately when `x` is set.

`dis` module shows that `STORE_GLOBAL` is used to set `x`:

```
>>> def f():
...     global x
...     x = 1
...
...
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(f)
  4           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              3 STORE_GLOBAL             0 (x)
              6 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              9 RETURN_VALUE
```

It is implemented in `ceval.c` as:

```
    TARGET(STORE_GLOBAL)
        w = GETITEM(names, oparg);
        v = POP();
        err = PyDict_SetItem(f->f_globals, w, v);
        Py_DECREF(v);
        if (err == 0) DISPATCH();
        break;
```

if `PyDict_SetItem()` is replaced with `PyObject_SetItem()` then CPython also works i.e., custom `__setitem__()` is called.

Comment: Thanks.  Since this is something that differs between python implementations, I think I'll stay away from having my program depend on it:-)