# Tracking a Python function's global accesses

Tags: python, python-2.7, cpython

I would like to be able to track which global variables a Python function accesses. My first attempt to do this involved creating a subclass of `dict` that logged its calls to `__getitem__` and `__setitem__`, and constructing a new function with that as the `globals`.

This sorta-kinda works in Python 3 (although I still haven't gotten builtins to work properly). However, it [looks like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13259749/how-to-override-setitem-for-a-functions-globals-dict) this doesn't work at all in Python 2, because CPython calls `PyDict_SetItem()` directly on the globals instead of `PyObject_SetItem()`.

What's the best way of doing the same thing in Python 2? Do I just have to inspect the bytecode for `LOAD_GLOBAL` instructions, or is there a better way?

EDIT: one disadvantage of the `LOAD_GLOBAL` approach is that I don't get to detect whether the function actually accesses the global variables--for instance, if global `foo` is accessed only in one branch, the approach detailed above can tell if that branch executed, whereas bytecode-reading won't. Another disadvantage is that this won't be able to catch variable accesses through `globals()[bar]`. These are fairly minor for my purposes, but it would be nice to solve them.

Comment: Interesting problem.  What's the big picture here? Are you interested in a particular function, or building a debugging tool?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out if I can make essentially a "super-memoizer" that caches results to disk across runs of the program (for especially expensive functions, of which I have a lot). This is one possible strategy.

Comment: If these are functions you have written, then why not write them to not access globals?  Or, access the globals through a helper function that you can hook into your caching system?

Comment: You might be able to use the fact that a module can be an instance of an object as described in the ActiveState recipe titled [Constants in Python](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/65207-constants-in-python/). This means you could replace the module you want to track accesses to with a custom object that facilitated doing it -- either as shown in the recipe or by making members of the object properties.

Comment: What about installing yourself as a debugger, and hooking every time `LOAD_GLOBAL` gets executed, instead of every time it just exists inside a function? (Obviously this won't help for `globals()[bar]`, much less for `g = foo.func_globals; g[bar]` or `g = sys._getframe().f_globals; g[bar]` or the like, but your existing code should already take care of that…)

Comment: Or, more simply, why not either have a list of functions, or just get the lists by introspecting all of your modules (you can even make _that_ dynamic with an import hook), then wrapping every global function, instead of trying to intercept every lookup of those functions. It seems like that should be a lot simpler, and a lot faster, and unless your modules are creating new globals programmatically at runtime it should have the effect you're looking for.

Comment: @NedBatchelder: That would be pretty inconvenient, especially for programs written like scripts, which typically have lots of globals. I'd like my solution to be minimally intrusive. I'm also hoping to be able to factor it out into a library.

Comment: @abarnert: Wrapping modules might help, but it won't do anything about functions accessing a global in their own module.

The debugger solution seems potentially good. Do you know how much of a performance hit it will cause?

Comment: I'm not suggesting wrapping modules, I'm suggesting wrapping the _functions_ so they don't look in the module globals in the first place. The only reason you'd need to do anything with the modules is if you want to hook them or introspect them to dynamically wrap all functions at runtime.

Comment: As for the debugger… no idea, but how hard is it to run your program under `pdb` and see if the difference is noticeable?

Comment: @abarnert--sorry, I started by replying to you and martineau at the same time, and accidentally confused some suggestions. Wrapping module functions has the problem of not wrapping non-function module members. I could replace those with proxy objects or something, but... yikes.